# Scala mixin Node trait

Tags: scala, mixins

I am trying to make a trait which I can mixing to an class to define it as a tree node.  Finding an elegant way of doing this is turning out to be problematic.

The following just doesn't work, as this.type causes a type mismatch when you assign a parent

```
trait Node {
  def parent:Option[this.type]
  def root:this.type =
    parent.fold(this)(_.root)
}
```

This kind of works but the T value could get miss-assigned, and the casting is pretty ugly.

```
trait Node[T <: Node[T]] {
  def parent:Option[T]
  def root:T =
    parent.fold(this)(_.root).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

Any ideas of a stricter approach?

Answer (score 3):

```
trait Node[+T] {
  def parent: Option[Node[T]]
  def root: Node[T] = parent.fold(this)(_.root) // root is node as well, isn't it?
}

class Foo extends Node[Foo] { def parent = None }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a self-type to avoid the cast:

```
trait Node[T <: Node[T]] { self: T =>
  def parent: Option[T]
  def root: T = parent.fold(this)(_.root)
}
```

You can additionally return `T with Node[T]` instead of plain `T`, but I'm not sure if that gives real benefits beyond what the self-type gives you:

```
trait Node[T <: Node[T]] { self: T =>
  def parent: Option[T with Node[T]]
  def root: T with Node[T] = parent.fold(this)(_.root)
}
```

Comment: You will probably need also a self type, `self: T =>`

Comment: Thanks; you're right. Though I'm no longer sure if this is any better than just adding a self-type and using plain `T`.

Comment: And because the types are ugly in my version, "not any better" would mean "significantly worse"..